# Tooltip movement when you change the zoom level in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

I am using the "Permanent Tooltip" as lable in my map as follows:

```
layer.bindTooltip(layer.feature.properties.Label, {offset: L.point(0, 170), direction: 'bottom', permanent:true }).openTooltip();
```

The result is fine as you can see here:

[image]

However, when I change the zoom level, it messes up as follows:

[image]

Any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can solve this issue is create a new point layer (Marker) that points the end of each line. Then assign the tooltip to the points. Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
dataType: "json",
url: "...",
success: function (earthquake) {
    PointLayer= L.geoJSON(earthquake, {
        style: function (feature) {
            return {
                color: '#000',
                opacity: 1
            };
        },
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlong) {
            return L.circle(latlong, 0);
        },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindTooltip(layer.feature.properties.PanelName, { offset: L.point(0, 0), direction: 'bottom', permanent: true, className: 'AAAA', direction:'left' }).openTooltip();
        }
    }).addTo(map);
```

Note that you should assign an HTML class (i.e. AAAA) to change the tooltip formatting (remove background color, ....). Also to remove the little triangle of the tooltip direction, you should add a new CSS statement as follows:

```
.AAAA {
box-shadow:none;
border:none;
background-color:transparent;
}
.leaflet-tooltip-top:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-bottom:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-left:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-right:before {
    border: none !important;
}
```