# How to bind a tooltip to the edge of a leaflet L.Circle?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a leaflet map where I have created several circles using `L.Circle`, the radius and position of these circles are updated live. I want to bind a tooltip or similar to the edge of these circles which will display some text. I have attached an image of what I am trying to achieve.

[image: Circle with text]

I have created my circle using:

```
circle = new L.Circle(point, {
    color: '#00F',
    opacity: 0.8,
}).addTo(map);
```

This works well and makes the following:

[image: My circle]

I am having difficulty replicating the connected text as seen above as I cannot bind anything to the circle. What is the best way to have a text field dynamically bound to the center bottom of the circle radius?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bind a [Tooltip](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#tooltip) to the circle, and use its `offset` option to place it at the bottom edge.  However, this is awkward as the offset is specified in pixels, so you have to convert the circle radius from metres to pixels at the current zoom level. As well as accounting for changes in the circle's radius, you also have to reposition the tooltip when the map is zoomed, and the Circle class doesn't have a convenient event to tell you when to do so.

A more robust approach is to create an invisible marker in the right place, and bind the tooltip to that (as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55008182/937094)). The marker can be positioned using the circle's coordinates, rather than a pixel offset, and will stay in the right place when the map is zoomed.

To automatically place the invisible marker, and update it when the circle's coordinates or radius changes, we can create a custom `TipCircle` class that extends the functionality of the normal `Circle`. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/vector/CircleMarker.js) for `CircleMarker` (Circle's parent class) helps figure out which functions to override:

```
L.TipCircle = L.Circle.extend({
  initialize: function(latlng, options, legacyOptions) {
    // Create invisible marker
    this._tip = L.circleMarker([0,0], {opacity: 0, radius: 0});
    // Initialize as a normal Circle
    L.Circle.prototype.initialize.call(this, latlng, options, legacyOptions);
  },
  redraw: function() {
    L.Circle.prototype.redraw.call(this);
    this._setTip();
  },
  onAdd: function() {
    L.Circle.prototype.onAdd.call(this);
    this._setTip();
    this._tip.addTo(map);
  },
  onRemove: function() {
    this._tip.remove();
    L.Circle.prototype.onAdd.call(this);
  },
  _setTip: function() {
    // Set the location for the tooltip to latitude of the bottom of the circle's
    // bounding box, and the longitude of its centre.
    this._tip.setLatLng([
      this.getBounds()._southWest.lat,
      this.getLatLng().lng]);
    // Set the label to the circle's radius in metres
    const tipText = String(this.getRadius());

    // Remove any old tooltip and attach the new one
    this._tip.unbindTooltip();
    this._tip.bindTooltip(tipText, {
                            direction: 'center',
                            permanent: true,
                            className: 'circleTip'
                          });
  }
});
L.tipCircle = (latlng, options, legacyOptions) => new L.TipCircle(latlng, options, legacyOptions);
```

You can use this new TipCircle class just the same as a normal Circle:

```
circle = (new L.TipCircle(point, {color: '#00F', opacity: 0.8})).addTo(map);
```

It will display the tooltip automatically, and keep it in the right place when you alter it with `circle.setLatLng()` or `circle.setRadius()`. The code above will also change the tooltip text to show the circle's current radius in metres. Edit the `_setTip()` method to convert it to km, or whatever you need.

You can also add some CSS to format the tooltip more like the one in your example:

```
.circleTip {
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 1px;
  font-size: x-small;
}
```